# Make grid column elements stretch with space-evenly

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have heard that grid is a superset of flexbox in terms of feature parity, i.e. everything what is possible with flexbox, is also possible with grid.

Essentially what I need is to have grid for 2 viewport sizes as follows:

```
a s
b s
c s
d d

a s
b s
c s
d s
```

And in the second case a-d to behave like flex-column with:

```
align-self: stretch;
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

Because content of the s is taller.

Currently this is implemented with two levels of nesting: row a-d and s. And a-d is flex-column. BUT on top of that I need to move d around with JavaScript. And that’s why I’m seeking for another solution.

So currently the layout is as follows: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/moVvyO?editors=1100), but I want the last paragraph on smaller viewport sizes to jump out of the article and take full width. If you wonder, why I need even sparser paragraphs, it's OK, content in the `aside` is also changed based on viewport size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you provide a sample of the relevent code(s) so that I can visualize this better? (thx)

Comment: @elbrant I've added a codepen. Did it clarify the question?

Comment: Still unsure about this. Adding a sample image to your question might help.